# Jumplist in .NET 6 Visual Studio 2022 how to create an item

Tags: c#, wpf, jump-list

I am trying to add a menuitem to the jumplist (i.e. `Create New`).

I am in `App.xaml` and I add the following markup:

```
<Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
    <JumpList.JumpList>
        <JumpList ShowRecentCategory="True"/>
    </JumpList.JumpList>
```

`JumpList ShowRecentCategory="True"/>` throws an error

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an Object.

I've been reading a lot of different blogs on how to add jumplist, though a lot of these are from 2009. I'm not seeing anything to add an item to the Jumplist for Windows 11 Visual Studio 2022.

For clarification the jumplist below is what Windows 11 looks like. I want to add custom items into my project. I am just messing around learning new stuff on WPF C#.

Any help is appreciated,

I'm not sure if I need to add a .dll file or any other references. I am using `using System.Windows.Shell` as well.

[image: This is the jumplist]

Comment: I tried freshly created WPF app of .NET 6.0 on Visual Studio 2022 and noticed the same message. But after rebuild, unload, then reload project, the message disappeared.

Comment: Yes same thing here... I'm not sure what it was. But I'll leave this up to ensure nothing else goes wrong